# iScroll not working with big images

Tags: iscroll

Im trying to create a pinch-zoomable image using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) library. It works fine with small images but when I use images bigger than the screen I cannot scroll through them (I can on desktop browsers, but not on mobile!).

[This link](http://www.bretemasoftware.com/image.html) takes to a live example of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it myself. Turns out the sample iScroll provides initializes the scrolling div with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);`, but when this event is fired images might not have been loaded so their size is reported as 0.

Simply replacing it with:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
```

fixes it.